# Formatting dates with datatables.net in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

I apologise if this is repeating a similar query. I'm new to stack overflow and have tried searching for similar but had no luck.

I'm trying to use datatables.net with react, and have managed to get reasonably far, however I am having trouble getting the sort function to play nicely with formatted dates.

Initially I used

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": 5,
        "data": "date",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return moment(data).format('L');
        },
        responsivePriority: 7
    }
]
```

However this would not sort correctly. Now I have installed the plugins via npm and placed the following at the top of the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Table, Grid, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import 'datatables.net-plugins/dataRender/datetime';
import 'datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css';
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-plugins/type-detection/date-uk');
require('datatables.net-responsive');
```

My column definition changed to:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": 5,
        "data": "date",
        "type": "date-uk",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return moment(data).format('L');
        },
        responsivePriority: 7
    }
]
```

However now I get the following for the datetime script:
`Cannot read property 'render' of undefined`

Has anyone had any luck doing this in react?

Comment: I've now tried moving the dataRender.datetime to a require after the date-uk requirement, but now I get told jquery is not defined.

Comment: Well, it would seem you're passing an uninitialized or incorrect variable to whatever needs to call `render`. Where are you actually passing this in as a component?

Comment: Yep, sorry, very new to react and was picking up where a developer left off. Turned out a lot of problems were sorted by applying global.jQuery = $;